# Filter UNION results based on MAX() of column

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries and their result sets are brought together with a UNION.

I'm trying to filter out the rows based on the `MAX()` of th FilterColumn, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
| PropDescription | PropCode | FilterColumn |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
| 476SADDR1       | Finland  |            2 |
| 477SADDR1       | Sweden   |            2 |
| 1SADDR1         | 2038     |            1 |
| 2SADDR1         | 2030     |            1 |
| 3SADDR1         | 15       |            1 |
| 4SADDR1         | 00000002 |            1 |
| 6SADDR1         | 500      |            1 |
| 8SADDR1         | 556      |            1 |
| 9SADDR1         | 821      |            1 |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+

SELECT
    PropDescription
    , PropCode
    , FilterColumn
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE 
            WHEN PL.Type = 11
                THEN PL.ADDR
            ELSE P.ADDR
            END AS N'PropDescription'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PL.TYPE = 3
                THEN P.CODE
            ELSE LPA.Value
            END AS N'PropCode'
        , 2 AS FilterColumn
    FROM PROPERTY PL
    INNER JOIN PROPLIST LP2 ON PL.ID = LP2.PropList
    INNER JOIN PROPERTY P ON LP2.Property = P.ID
    INNER JOIN PropAttribute LPA ON LPA.PropList = PL.ID
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND PL.ID IN (SELECT Property from PROPLIST where PropList IN (47,46))
        AND P.TYPE = 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE 
            WHEN PL.Type = 11
                THEN PL.ADDR
            ELSE P.ADDR
            END AS N'PropDescription'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PL.TYPE = 3
                THEN P.CODE
            ELSE LPA.Value
            END AS N'PropCode'
        , 1 AS FilterColumn
    FROM PROPERTY PL
    INNER JOIN PROPLIST LP2 ON PL.ID = LP2.PropList
    INNER JOIN PROPERTY P ON LP2.Property = P.ID
    LEFT JOIN PropAttribute LPA ON LPA.PropList = PL.ID
    WHERE 1 = 1
     AND PL.ID IN (SELECT Property from PROPLIST where PropList IN (1,2,3,4))
     AND PL.TYPE = 3
    ) AS ResultSet
```

I know this is quite simple, but I can't just figure it out right now.

Expected output is:

```
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
| PropDescription | PropCode | FilterColumn |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
| 476SADDR1       | Finland  |            2 |
| 477SADDR1       | Sweden   |            2 |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: So what would your expected output look like, based on the sample data you've provided?

Comment: Hmm, from what I read I am missing additional condition on how you want the filter to work on the FilterColumn.... Until now I understand this
    SELECT
    PropDescription
    , PropCode
    , FilterColumn
FROM
    (YourSubQuery)
    GROUP BY PropDescription, PropCode
    HAVING FilterColumn = MAX(FilterColumn)

Comment: @shree.pat18 Updated my question with expected output.

Comment: @DimiToulakis Updated my question with expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
( --Your union),

 filtered as
(*, rank() over (order by filtercolumn desc) rank from cte)

select * from filtered
where rank = 1
```

Comment: Yes, ranking.. that was it! I know I used something before, but couldn't remember what.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu No worries, we all get stumped by these things every now and then!